# Change the order of the y-axis values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axes

I'm using the `ggplot` R package, I did this plot with the code below:

```
p3 = data.frame(cbind(c(1:70),
                      c("G1" ,  "G2" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G2"  ,   "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1",  
                        "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G2" ,  "G1" ,  "G2"  ,   "G1" ,  "G1"  ,
                        "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G2" , "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1"  ,
                        "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" , 
                        "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G2" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" , 
                        "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G1" ,  "G2"),
                      c(rep("B",35),rep("C",15),rep("A",20))
))

colnames(p3)=c("Num","L" , "G")

library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)

pp <- ggplot(p3, aes(Num, G)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = L), colour = "white") 
pp + theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, size=7,vjust=0.5)) + # scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic()
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#990000","#E69F00","#999999"))
```

[image]

**I would like to change the order of y-axis values according to the number of bars (= variable G)**

The expected plot:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change levels for `p3$G` according to sorted table of `p3$G` variable:

```
p3$G <- factor(p3$G, names(sort(table(p3$G))))

sort(table(p3$G))
# C  A  B 
# 15 20 35
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution !

Answer (score 1):

You can set how you want the `G` column of your dataframe to be ordered by setting it to type factor, and setting the levels. This can all be done with:

```
levels(p3$G) <- c("C", "A", "B")
```